# gRPC round robin load balancer

Tags: grpc

I'm trying to use the round robin (RR) load balancer (LB) with a single backend. Is it possible to have RR LB create multiple connections (sub channels) for a single backend without having to write a custom LB implementation?

Comment: One trick you can try is to change the resolver to send multiple addresses for the same backend. Note that most balancers also deduplicate the addresses, so you may need to assign address attributes to stop them from being deduped.

Comment: Do you have an example that we can reference?